# How do you make an underline under the heading that is slightly longer than the text?

Tags: html, css

I need to have an underline that is longer than the text. Like maybe fifty pixels longer than what it was before.

I tried looking up examples and tutorials online but I couldn't find anything. Here's an example of what I want:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85HVg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your text in a div, give it some `padding-inline` to make it slightly longer than the text. Then use `border-bottom` to create an underline.

```css
.text {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: max-content;
  padding-block: 5px;
  padding-inline: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I decrease/increase the space of the border from the h1?

Comment: You can either use `padding-block` or `padding-bottom` on the outside div to create some space between the text and border.

Comment: That isn't working for me, possibly because rather than using a div, I'm using a heading.